# I am going to + infinitive + now

Tags: grammar

I regularly use the above sentence structure in daily life but my partner keeps pointing out that putting “now” at the end is not allowed because “going to” indicates the future and “now” indicates the present.

On the other hand I believe that “now” can also mean “very soon”, in which case it would be correct.

For example: “I am going to watch TV now” is considered wrong by her.

Could we get some arguments to help us settle this? Thanks!

Comment: Your partner has to learn actual English grammar, instead of what they tell you in school. There is no prohibition about mentioning different times in the same sentence in English. Plus, _going to_ **doesn't** mean "future"; it means _intend to_. The _now_ tells the listener when the intention is intended for. And, it's not a matter of argument; it's a matter of fact.

Comment: No need to be harsh. She is an applied linguist so I think what they told her in school probably has some merit. Do you have any documentation to back this up?

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the claim that one should not use two tenses in one sentence? People occasionally ask about it here, so I get the idea that some people are teaching it, but there's no rule that anybody can point to. There are a lot of crazy ideas in language teaching, which go viral and become zombies, like split infinitives.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can use it in any tense you want to.

[Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/going+to)

> going to (do something)
>
> About to; apt to; will.

e.g. He was going to change the light bulb.